# Отображение кириллических имён файлов в git status

Tags: git, utf-8

Добавляю в кагалог файл с названием на кириллице
(или просто не-*ASCII*), и получаю:

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
    "\320\260\320\261\320\262\320\263\320\264.txt"
```

Как сделать нормальное отображение?

Answer (score 6):

Используйте опцию [`core.quotePath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corequotePath):

> core.quotePath
>
> Commands that output paths (e.g. `ls-files`, `diff`),
> will quote "unusual" characters in the pathname by enclosing the pathname in
> double-quotes and escaping those characters with backslashes in the same way
> C escapes control characters (e.g. `\t` for TAB, `\n` for
> LF, `\\` for backslash) or bytes with values larger than 0x80
> (e.g. octal `\302\265` for "micro" in UTF-8).  If this variable is
> set to false, bytes higher than 0x80 are not considered "unusual" any more.
> Double-quotes, backslash and control characters are always escaped regardless of
> the setting of this variable.  A simple space character is not considered
> "unusual". Many commands can output pathnames completely verbatim using the
> `-z` option. The default value is true.

Соответственно, эту опцию надо установить в `false`:

```
$ git config --global core.quotePath false
```

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
    абвгд.txt
```